# Can "to do something" refer to a noun with wh question?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, relative-clauses

Let's think of a normal sentence such as "I found **a book with 500 pages**."

Everyone knows that we can't make its question form like

"Which book did you find with 500 pages?"
because the connection between "book" and "with 500 pages" is lost. So you can't ask this question.

Now, let's say our original sentence is

"I found **a book to learn about the evolution theory from**."

That bold part is a phrase there and "**a book**" and "**to learn about the evolution theory from**" is attached to each other obviously. We can't separate them.
So do you think that it is possible to ask its question like

"Which book did you find **to learn about the evolution theory from** ?"

In my opinion, this question is also totally wrong. Why? Because there is no connection between "to learn..from" and "book" anymore.
They are not attached anymore. So I don't accept the idea that the last question is grammatically correct and natural in English.
Do you agree with me?

Comment: "Everyone knows that we can't make its question form like

"Which book did you find with 500 pages?" - this is a perfectly normal sentence. Which man did you see with three dogs?

Comment: Disagree. Which man did you see with three dogs, is OK because it's using a different structure however, we can't ask a question like "Which book did you find with 500 pages?". What does it mean? 
I read many linguistics researches and there were lots of examples about it. For instance, it was written that we can't ask a question like
"What book did you find about the second world war?" It has no meaning. You assume that "with 500 pages" is still attached to the noun "book" with wh question, however, in English rules, it is not possible.

Comment: [When you got into the room whom did you find with Mr. Reynolds?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22did+you+find+with%22) Perfectly normal English, apart from the fact that most of us just use ***who*** rather than ***whom*** today. And I expect there will be at least hundreds if not thousands more examples of the construction in that link. I see no "question" here - just someone who's mistakenly picked up a false "rule".

Comment: Person A: Looking through the books written by the children in the class, I found one book with thirty pages, one with fifty, and one with five hundred! Person B: Which book did you find with five hundred pages? Person A: Joe Smith's book.

Comment: Well, if this sentence is correct, why was that linguistic document saying: "The sentence "what book did you find about the second world war" is wrong ?@MichaelHarvey

Comment: @FumbleFingers you are changing the structure of the sentence. In your sentence, "with Mr.Reynolds" functions as an adverbial prepositional phrase and that's why it is perfectly normal English. 

However, in my sentence, "with 500 pages" is not about the verb "find", it is totally about the noun "a book" and when you ask a question like "What book did you find with 500 pages?", it means the connection between the adjectival prepositional phrase "with 500 pages" and the noun "book" is lost. So, "with 500 pages" doesn't refer to "book" anymore.

Comment: "Which book did you find **from which** to learn about **the theory of evolution**?"

Comment: @Jawel - what "linguistic document"? We cannot see it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I was also looking for it but can't find it, unfortunately.

Comment: The English language doesn't prohibit asking about anything ... even about books with 500 pages. If a linguist appears to take exception to that, it may be that they are talking about something else.

Comment: @Jawel: I think you're splitting hairs with your syntactic breakdown there. Would you also reject *Is this the only book you could find with 500 pages?* I'm guessing you have a problem with that because you think the prepositional clause should appear immediately after the noun if refers to: *Is this the only book with 500 pages you could find?*, but I have to say that's a mistaken idea. There are many contexts where the first version would be *preferred* by the careful writer/speaker.

Comment: Well, I found a different linguistics explaining what I'm trying to say.
In the link I am going to leave below, you can see that those questions are wrong.

- What did he sell a book about?
- What did he drop a book about? 
@Lawrence If English language doesn't prohibit asking about anything, Could you please tell me why they are wrong according to that research?
http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch12.html

Comment: The first question on that page that is labeled ‘ungrammatical’ is “How have they forgotten which problem they have to solve?” It links to [an earlier section](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch11.html#bad-wh). Note that Chomsky uses the term *grammar* in a sense that I think bears the influence of theoretical computer science, as opposed to the generic sense of ‘does this make sense to a native speaker?’ Further, in the linked example, the issue was that a constructed question didn’t match the intended answer.

Comment: I think I understand what you’re trying to ask now. I plan to answer more fully when I have a bit more spare time.

Comment: Or you could just keep things simple (and correct) by saying, "a book on evolution theory."

Comment: “What did you find with 500 pages?” elicits the desired response, but so does “What did you find to read and how long is it?” and also “The task was to acquire a book with 500 pages, how is it you have returned with all the money I gave you?”.   (These put the emphasis on different words in the response: The last one emphasizes ***found***)

Comment: And “What have you found to learn about evolution theory from?”

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing/conflating two ideas:

- whether a question is grammatically correct in English; and
- whether a question naturally elicits a given answer.

Via links you provided in comments under your question, I found a useful example that highlights this difference:

> Indirect question:
>   (23)  a.      They have forgotten which problem they should solve by Fourier analysis.
>   b.    *   How have they forgotten which problem they should solve?
>   - Be sure to interpret How in (23b) as modifying the complement verb solve, as indicated by the trace, not the matrix verb forgotten. In other words, a possible answer to (23b) is by Fourier analysis, but not by succumbing to Alzheimer's.
>   [- Wh movement in English](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch11.html#bad-wh)

The intended answer there was "Fourier analysis" (item 23a), but the question in item 23b doesn't elicit that answer.

Likewise, your first sample question

> Which book did you find with 500 pages?

doesn't elicit the intended answer

> I found a book with 500 pages.

Likewise with your second sample question. The "which book" question doesn't match the intended answer of "I found it".

However, just because a question doesn't match an intended answer, it doesn't mean that the question itself is ungrammatical. Both sample questions make sense grammatically.

The question's title asks:

> Can “to do something” refer to a noun with wh question?

I take that to ask whether something like "I found it" (*cf* your "to do something") can refer to a noun like "a book" (*cf* your "noun") by asking "Which book did you find?" (*cf* your "with wh question").

The answer is that they are not equivalent: "I found it" isn't a noun - it's a whole statement/assertion/proposition. However, the assertion does refer to a noun ("it"), which is also used in the *wh* question. The answer to the *wh* question, however, should be a noun (or noun phrase) that is more specific than that mentioned in the question.

That is, if the question asks "Which book with 500 pages did you find?", the reply "I found a book with 500 pages." isn't a particularly satisfying answer. More acceptable answers include "I found the *white* book with 500 pages." or "I found the *original* book with 500 pages." etc. In each case, the answer narrows the universe referenced in the *wh* question, thereby addressing the operative part of the question, namely, the word "Which".